# Substring replacement in a string in C

Tags: c, string, substring

everyone! I decided to make an account on this site seeking for help because I could not find anything that can help me. I have a problem which requires multiple steps:
1) Read a string from keyboard;
2) Read an integer that represents the number of substrings that you want to modify ( By modifying it means to transform all of the characters of the string into " * " );
3)Read all of the substrings that need to be modified;
4) Print the initial string modified.
I tried to make it with little steps by firstly managing to do it with one substring, but I don't know  how to do it when I read multiple substrings. So, here are the versions
VERSION 1

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{   
    int n;
    char str[5120];
    char substr[100];
    printf("Type the string:\n");
    gets(str);
    printf("\nType the substring which you would like to modify:");
    gets(substr);
    char *p;
    p = strstr(str,substr);
        if (*p != '\0')
            {
                for( int j=0 ; j< strlen(substr); j++)
                        {
                            *p = '*';
                            p++;
                        }
                }
    printf("\nThe modified string is:\n");
    for ( int i=0 ; i< strlen(a) ; i++)
            {
                printf("%c",a[i]);
            }
    return 0;
}
```

AND THE VERSION IN WHICH I TRIED TO MODIFY MULTIPLE

````
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{   
    int n;
    char str[5129];
    char substr[n][100];
    printf("Type the string:\n");
    gets(str);
    printf("How many substrings to modify?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nType the substrings:");
    for( int i=0 ; i< n ; i++)
        {
            scanf("%s",substr[i]);
            printf(" ");
        }
    for ( int i=0; i < n; i++)
        {
            char *p;
            p = strstr(str,substr[i]);
            if (*p != '\0')
                {
                    for( int j=0 ; j< strlen(cuv[i]); j++)
                        {
                            *p = '*';
                            p++;
                        }
                }
        }
    printf("\nThe modified string is:\n");
    for ( int i=0 ; i< strlen(str) ; i++)
            {
                printf("%c",str[i]);
            }
    return 0;
}```
I guess for the n times that I cycle to the string I have to allocate memory somewhere, or I don't know..
Please, I need some help! Thank you!
````

Comment: You just get the first substring, modify the string, then get the next and modify the (modified) string, then the next and the next....

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, Paul Ogilvie! But the problem requires that all of the substrings need to be red first and afterwards they need to be modified. It's a model for an exam.

Comment: Then you read the substrings into an array or list and process them one-by-one (how difficult can it be to come up with this?)

Comment: The problem specifies that the substrings need to be inputed from keyboard one at a time with " " space between them, Paul Ogilvie! I don't understand what you are suggesting, I am sorry.

Comment: I say that the fact that the substrings need to be _input_ one at a time does not imply they have to be _processed_ directly after input. How are you doing now on your assignment? Still having problems?

Answer (score 1):

So I edited my answer based on your and @PaulOgilvie suggestions. I hope that the program now works as you expected.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 5129

void replaceSubstring(char *p, int len){
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++, p++){
        *p = '*';
        }
    }

int main() {   
    int n = 0;
    char str[MAX_SIZE];
    char substr[n][100];

    printf("Type the string:\n");
    fgets(str, MAX_SIZE, stdin);

    printf("How many substrings to modify?");
    scanf("%d",&n);


    for( int i=0 ; i< n ; i++) {
        printf("\nType the substring number %d:", i+1);
            scanf("%s",substr[i]);
    }

    char *p;
    for ( int i=0; i < n; i++){
         p = strstr(str, substr[i]);
         while(p != NULL) {
             replaceSubstring(p, strlen(substr[i]));
             p = strstr(str, substr[i]);
             }
    }

    printf("\nThe modified string is:\n");
    for ( int i=0 ; i< strlen(str) ; i++)
            {
                printf("%c",str[i]);
            }
    return 0;
}
```